# MyBatis and DBMS_OUTPUT

Tags: oracle, debugging, stored-procedures, mybatis

I am using Oracle/MyBatis and trying to debug a stored procedure with an enormous amount of parameters.  Inside the stored procedure I get a `ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column`

So my initial approach would be to do like `dbms_output.put_line` in the stored procedure to try to see what the values are right before the offending statement.  Without MyBatis, I would ordinarily open up a sqlplus script and type `set serveroutput on` and then run my stored procedure at some later point to see all the debug messages come out.  With MyBatis, I cannot figure out how (if possible) to get these debug statements.

I have the ibatis and sql debuggers set for DEBUG and I use log4j to log everything for my Tomcat 6 application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DBMS_OUTPUT` package has a few other procedures that you could use.  `DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE` functions much like the SQL*Plus command `set serveroutput on` in that it allocates a buffer for `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` to write to.  `DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINE` can be used to fetch the data written to that buffer by previous calls to `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`.  So it should be possible to call the `ENABLE` function, call the procedure which writes a number of lines to the buffer, and then call `GET_LINE` (or `GET_LINES`) to fetch the data that was written to the `DBMS_OUTPUT` buffer and write that data to your logs.

It may be simpler, however, to redirect the logging to an Oracle database table rather than trying to use `DBMS_OUTPUT`.  One common approach is to create your own package that has a switch to determine whether to write to `DBMS_OUTPUT` or whether to write to a table.  Something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE p
AS
  procedure l( p_str IN VARCHAR2 );
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY p
AS
  g_destination INTEGER;
  g_destination_table    CONSTANT INTEGER := 1;
  g_destination_dbms_out CONSTANT INTEGER := 2;  

  PROCEDURE l( p_str IN VARCHAR2 )
  AS 
  BEGIN
    IF( g_destination = g_destination_dbms_out )
    THEN
      dbms_output.put_line( p_str );
    ELSE
      INSERT INTO log_table ...
    END IF;
  END;

  BEGIN
    g_destination := <<determine which constant to set it to.  This
                       may involve querying a `SETTINGS` table, looking
                       at the environment, or something else>>
  END;
END;
```

Comment: Yeah I guess I really have to go with the second approach you mention, the switch.  Probably not worth the extra effort worrying about how to get it to Tomcat logs.

Comment: For the record, [here's how to fetch `DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINES` content from JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47831073/521799) (and thus from MyBatis)