# Is there any way to get the dbms_out.putline() output when calling the stored procedure using Spring jdbcTemplate?

Tags: spring, plsql, jdbctemplate, dbms-output

My Stored Procedure have some dbms_output.put_line() which I am using to get the output in the comma separated result.

Now I need to get that using Spring jdbcTemplate.

Is there any way to do that ?

or is there any way other way to get the required out put in comma separated form ?

for example : 
below is the output format I need :

Section,TIER1,FUND_ID,FUND_NAME,TRADING_DESK_FULL,BUSINESS_UNIT,DIVISION,ASSET_TYPE,PFL_V_NUMERATOR,PFL_V_DENOMINATOR,PER_FUND_VALUE,THRESHOLD,THRESHOLD_BREACH,PER_FUND_LIMIT,LIMIT_BREACH
Per_FUND_VALUE_EXCLUDING_AB,DBA,59911,Secondary Opportunitie Fund III L.P.,Alternatives - 1248,Alternative - 1388,DWS,N/A,19666958,1120962063,1.75,2.4,0,3,0
Per_FUND_VALUE_EXCLUDING_AB,DBA,50748,Energy Select Fund (U.S.) L.P.,WM,WM,DW,N/A,144490.5408,239444140.4,.05,2.4,0,3,0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting output from dbms\_output.get\_lines using JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830370/getting-output-from-dbms-output-get-lines-using-jdbc)