# Passing parameter to callableSatatement - ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Tags: java, jdbc, parameters, callable-statement

I have a PL/SQL query with parameter:

```java
plSqlQuery =    "declare "
              + "  num integer := 1000;"
              + "  myStr varchar2(100):= ?;"
              + "begin "
              + "  dbms_output.put_line('abc');"
              + "  dbms_output.put_line('hello');"
              + "  dbms_output.put_line(myStr);"
              + "end;"
```

My Java method is something like this:

```java
public static void getData(String sqlQuery) throws SQLException, IOException{
    Statement s =conn.createStatement();
    try{
    s.executeUpdate("begin dbms_output.enable();end;);
    s.executeUpdate(sqlQuery);
    
    try{
    CallableStatement call = conn.prepareCall("declare num integer = 10000; begin dbms_output.get_lines(?, num); end;)
    }
    call.registerOutParameter(1,Types.ARRAY, "DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY");
    call.execute();
    
     Array array = null;
                    try {
                        array = call.getArray(1);
                        System.out.println(Arrays.asList((Object[]) 
                 array.getArray()));
                    }
                    finally {
                        if (array != null)
                            array.free();
                    }
```

Having both above now, I would like to execute my getData method, but I don't know how to pass a parameter to it (myStr).

Can you please tell my where in my Java method I should set my string parameter?

Should it be something like

```
s.setString(x, "abcdefg");
```

or

```
call.setString(2, "abcdefg");
```

it gives me an Oracle error like

> ORA-01008: not all variables bound

I tried both to be honest but did not succeed.

Comment: call.setString(x, "abcdefg");

Comment: and better use executeQuery()

Comment: Hi @kofemann,
I added 
call.setString(2, "abcdefg");  call.executeQuery(): but I'm getting an error like "ORA-01008: not all variables bound"

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830370/getting-output-from-dbms-output-get-lines-using-jdbc Maybe you should also refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html

Comment: I did, but there is no parameter which is passed to the oracle pl/sql. Without param it works fine, I agree

Comment: I have written code that does what (I believe) you want and it runs without error. However I can't think of a use-case where you would run PL/SQL code from JDBC that simply writes to standard output. Is that really all you want to do?

Comment: Yes, unfortunatelly that's the requirement :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing your string `plSqlQuery` as the parameter to your `getData()` method (e.g. by calling `getData(plSqlQuery)`) then you will run into an ORA-01008 'not all variables bound' error, because you're not specifying a value for the `?` placeholder.

You can't use an ordinary `Statement` with placeholders, you must use a `PreparedStatement` instead.

Try replacing the line

```java
    s.executeUpdate(sqlQuery);
```

with

```java
    try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery)) {
        pstmt.setString(1, "Some Value Here");
        pstmt.execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
It works with 3 different statements :(

```
Statement s = conn.createStatement();
s.executeUpdate("begin dbms_output.enable();end;);

PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
ps.setString(1, "abcdefg");

 CallableStatement call = conn.prepareCall("declare num integer = 10000; begin dbms_output.get_lines(?, num); end;)
 call.registerOutParameter(1,Types.ARRAY, "DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY");
 call.execute();
```