# How to print or return a value from anonymous block in PL/SQL without using dbms_output?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to use PL/SQL block in zabbix (ODBC connection), but I can't return the value. I need to use PL/SQL block because I need to use the command `pragma exception_init`

For example, to print the value of the following code:

```
declare begin dbms_output.put_line('x'); end;
```

I need to use `set serverouput on` in SQLPLUS.

But ODBC and Zabbix does not understand the command `set serverouput on`. How to return the value using ODBC?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/47830370/1509264

Comment: Or assign a value to a bind variable and access the value of that from your code?

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly what you are trying to do?  It is conceivable that you just want `begin :variable := 'x'; end;` but I have no idea what Zabbix is or whether it would accept that sort of construct.  It is conceivable that you want to run a bunch of `dbms_output.get_line` calls after the script runs to fetch data from the `dbms_output` buffer.  Neither of those would be particularly idiomatic approaches, though, so my guess is you're approaching your problem from the wrong angle

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to run your PL/SQL block using a PL/SQL function in a common table expression. The results are returned as regular SQL data instead of trying to send it to DBMS_OUTPUT.

```
SQL> with function get_text return varchar2 is
  2  begin
  3     return 'x';
  4  end;
  5  select get_text
  6  from dual
  7  /

GET_TEXT
--------
x
```

There are a few potential problems with this approach. The syntax only works on Oracle 12c and above. The statement terminator can cause some problems depending on your environment - you will likely need to remove the slash from the end. And some environments won't even allow you to run this because they incorrectly think that all SELECT statements must begin with the keyword `SELECT`.